# Is it possible to keep the scope in angular.js, and to modify the template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, template-engine

I am quite stuck in my directive : This is part of the code :

```
 var $template = angular.element("<div></div>");
 $template.append($compile(template)(scope));
 $template.find('block').html($block.html());
 $element.replaceWith($template.html());
 $compile($element.contents())(scope);
```

I try to retrieve the content of a template, make it append to the layout, and compile.

I loose every associated scope by doing this. (I.E. : a ng-click on a  doesn't work)

Is it possible to keep the associated scope of an already compiled template ? If not, what alternative do I have ?

Thanks a lot,

Rémi

**EDIT**
See the comment for an example in plunker,
thanks again

**EDIT**

The given directive should be able to do the following :
view.html :

`<layout extends='/layout.html'>
  <block name="content">TOTO</block>
  <block name="content2">TOTO2</block>
</layout>`

layout.html :

```
<navbar></navbar>
   <block name="content"></block>
   <block name="content2"></block>
 <footer></footer>
```

output :

`<navbar></navbar>
   <block name="content">TOTO</block>
   <block name="content2">TOTO2</block>
 <footer></footer>`

Does this make any sense ?

**EDIT**

Is it possible to do something like :
$element.replaceWith($template);
knowing that the template is already on the DOM?

Thanks guys

Comment: Could you code with plunkr?

Comment: Yes sure, I'll post it asap

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/e3sRi7?p=info Thanks by advance. In this example, the brackets are not working, I don't know why, but in my app, I am more close, and only the events are not attached

Comment: I don't get it, what is the purpose of this directive in the first place?  this doesn't look like something that should be necessary.  Aside from that, I don't think it's actually doing what you think it is;  transclusion is a tricky beast.

Comment: I am trying to make a layout templating system, but I am quite stuck, indeed. I will go back to something more basic...

Comment: `.html()` returns a string - once you do that, it doesn't really matter that you compiled/linked the directives of those elements that produced that string. You need to `.append`, `replaceWith`, etc... the actual DOM element objects that you linked. But in any case, **what** is the ultimate objective of this directive? Edit your question to show what it's supposed to do for a given input. Saying "layout templating system" is too vague

Comment: I have edited the question, thank for your answer.

Comment: My new question is the following : is it possible to do something like $element.replaceWith(myTemplate); knowing that myTemplate is already compiled on the DOM ? Thanks

Comment: have you looked at ng-transclude?

Comment: Yes sure, I am doing kind of the same...

Comment: Well, it seems as though you're reinventing the wheel; since what you are describing can be easily accomplished with a directive that uses the transclude option?

Comment: Indeed, it can be easy with transclude. But I intend to do a templating version with multiple blocks, which could be easily replaced.

Comment: I have edited to show what I want to do. But I think that you're right, it's too complicated for a so poor result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to do it properly !!!

In fact, if you want all the event and the scope attached, you've to wait for the compile event, which is done with a $timeout(fn,0);
Disgusting, I know, but works fine !!!